# Atom-editor beautify gives php-cs-fixer error

Tags: atom-editor

I'm pretty much new to Atom editor, but setup some nice packages like Atom Beautify. After using it in a html / php file I'm getting the error **"Could not find 'php-cs-fixer' . The program may not be installed.** The strange thing is, I did install the package php-cs-fixer but nothing happens.

Anyone got an idea how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, for the not programmers here:

I installed php-cs-fixer via [Brew for mac](http://brew.sh) . Brew enables (wget) command lines via terminal. After installing brew, type `brew install homebrew/php/php-cs-fixer` in terminal and it will install the PHP-CS-Fixer .

Done!